# jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

For some reason I can't use `runat="server"` as an attribute for the input tag in order for the jQuery to display the image button and work. Is something wrong without `runat="server"`? It works fine. And I want the format to be "yyyy/mm/dd" and also I need it for the server because this is where I check to see if the date manually entered is a valid date and that it matches the accepted format. I really want to use an `asp:button` but since I can't use `runat="server"` attribute I don't know what to do since that is required for asp controls

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ showOn: "both", 
                                  buttonImage: "/Content/img/calendar.gif", 
                                  buttonImageOnly: true });
  }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it changes your id from "#datepicker" to "form1_ctl01_ctl05_datepicker" or something when you use runat='server'

EDIT:
For a solution, you could pick it up based on css class rather than ID

```
<input id='datepicker' runat='server' class='datepicker' />

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ showOn: "both", 
                              buttonImage: "/Content/img/calendar.gif", 
                              buttonImageOnly: true });
});
```

Comment: so when I put runat server it changes the id to ct101_ct105_datepicker?..and I dont understand what you mean by the second part

Comment: asp.net 'server' controls (runat=server) have their id attribute changed based on the various containers, master pages, etc that a control is embedded in.  This is to get around having multiple controls having the same 'id' in asp.net source to not violate XHTMLs rule of id values cannot be repeated

Answer (score 2):

For controls with runat="server", aspnet generates its own, rather ugly ids for the rendered html controls.

If your script is on actual page, you can replace
 $("#datepicker") with $("#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>"),
which will output the mangled id that aspnet generates, or, as Jimmy suggested, target it with a css class instead.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

When using the `runat='server'` tag, add `clientidmode='static'` to your element tag to prevent mangling of the generated id. On complicated or nested forms this may mess with the uniqueness of your control ids, which is why they are prefixed by default with the id of the element's parent(s).

p.s. The css class is probably the best way (IMHO) to handle datepickers, so the accepted answer looks fine.